# Selenium Java - how to extract a number from a html through Selenium

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I need to extract a number (Code) from a html. I have the next String that extract all in html:

```
String value = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"htmlSourceContent\"]")).getText();
```

I just want to extract the code (numbers)

This is the html:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
    <style>
      /* Email styles need to be inline */
    </style>
  </head>

  <body>
    <h1>Security Code</h1>

<p>
  Please enter the code <b>394013</b>.
</p>

  </body>
</html>
```

That code is random `<b>394013</b>.`

Comment: Is that really the entirety of the HTML of the page?

Comment: Yes: It's a body of an email.

Comment: `String value = driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("b")).getText();`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The correct solution for this is the next:

```
WebElement myElement = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.id("htmlSourceContent")));
    String myText = ((JavascriptExecutor)driver).executeScript("return arguments[0].childNodes[23].textContent;", myElement).toString();
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below xpath.

```
 //h1[normalize-space(.)='Security Code']/following-sibling::p/b
```

[image]

Comment: org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"xpath","selector":" //h1[normalize-space(.)='Security Code']/following-sibling::p/b"} .  As I see, this is not possible.

Comment: I am able to print the text successfully with `print(driver.find_element_by_xpath("//h1[normalize-space(.)='Security Code']/following-sibling::p/b").text)`

Comment: The  `NoSuchElement` exception might occur even if you try to access the element before it loads. You can add explicit wait, so that it will wait until the element is displayed.